# Does Amazon AWS something if I dont apply update security packages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

Sometimes I have noted that If I don't apply updated security packages in some EC2 instances on AWS then instances run slower. I have seen it repeatedly on different machines. Is it possible that Amazon is applying some policies for machines that are not updated?

Comment: No they don’t do that. At least not for EC2. https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/

Answer (score 1):

AWS has zero insight into what you run on an Amazon EC2 instance. You are responsible for installing and maintaining the operating system, applications and data. AWS is responsible for providing the platform that enables the virtual machine.

Every Amazon EC2 instance is given resources (CPU, RAM, Network) based on the Instance Type. The same instance type will always receive the same amount of resources, and the resources are not over-subscribed.

Therefore, any slowdown that you might observe would be related to the operating system and software that you are running on the instance. You can use standard monitoring tools to inspect the operating system to investigate what might be happening.